ImportError when trying to import the "cuml" library
Summary:
I am encountering an ImportError when trying to import the cuml library in a conda environment on Ubuntu 24.04. Here are the steps I followed and the errors I encountered.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a new conda environment:
conda create --prefix ./env jupyter python=3.8


Install the cuml library from the rapidsai channel:
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge cuml=21.12 cudatoolkit=11.0

This installation worked fine, and everything seemed to download successfully.

Start the Jupyter server:
jupyter notebook


Run the following in a Jupyter cell:
import cuml



Error Message:
ImportError: cannot import name 'MachAr' from 'numpy'

Details of the ImportError:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import cuml

File ~/Desktop/cuML-problem/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cuml/__init__.py:17
      1 #
      2 # Copyright (c) 2021, NVIDIA CORPORATION.
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # limitations under the License.
     15 #
---> 17 from cuml.common.base import Base
     18 from cuml.common.handle import Handle
     19 import cuml.common.cuda as cuda

File ~/Desktop/cuML-problem/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cuml/common/__init__.py:17
      1 #
      2 # Copyright (c) 2019-2020, NVIDIA CORPORATION.
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # limitations under the License.
     15 #
---> 17 from cuml.common.array import CumlArray
     18 from cuml.common.array_sparse import SparseCumlArray
     20 # utils

File ~/Desktop/cuML-problem/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cuml/common/array.py:17
      1 #
      2 # Copyright (c) 2020-2021, NVIDIA CORPORATION.
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # limitations under the License.
     15 #
---> 17 import cupy as cp
     18 import numpy as np
     19 import operator

File ~/Desktop/cuML-problem/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py:394
    392 from numpy import finfo  # NOQA
    393 from numpy import iinfo  # NOQA
--> 394 from numpy import MachAr  # NOQA
    396 from numpy import find_common_type  # NOQA
    397 from numpy import issctype  # NOQA

ImportError: cannot import name 'MachAr' from 'numpy' (/home/john/Desktop/cuML-problem/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py)

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Found a related issue suggesting to downgrade numpy to 1.23:

Ran the command:
conda install numpy=1.23


Encountered the following error:
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides numpy-base 1.23.3 py310h375b286_0 needed by numpy-1.23.3-py310hac523dd_0




Attempted to install the cuml library in a conda environment with Python 3.12:

Encountered similar dependency issues:
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package cuml-21.12.00-cuda11_py37_g04c4927f3_0 requires python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed




Attempted to install cuml without specific versions in an environment with Python 3.12:

Encountered the following error:
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides cuda92 needed by libcuml-0.5.1-cuda9.2_0





Environment Details:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Conda Version: 24.5.0
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
NVIDIA Driver Version: 535.183.01
Cuda Version: 11.0

Question:
How can I resolve the ImportError and successfully import the cuml library in my conda environment? Is there a specially series of steps I have to take to do this?

As to your attempted workaround: the cuml stuff with Python 3.12 seems to be a known open issue here.

The numpy version you have installed is too new

@talonmies You mean I nead <1.22?

I mean you need to do some research. The version of rapids you are using requires a deprecated and now removed numpy feature. You will need to check changelogs and release notes to work out when that happened and select the numpy version accordingly

@John Research enough. The instruction for creating the conda environment for cuML, which you are using, was a bad one which worked somewhere in the past but not works anymore. Just use the official guide.

@JohnCarter: In the edit to the question you claim that the downgrade of numpy didn't "solve your error", but it absolutely did.  You are not getting numpy related import errors any more. The error you have now is completely unrelated to numpy. Now you have a numba incompatibility.
